# sorting an STL List after all pushbacks or just use Multimap?

Tags: list, stl, multimap

We were using a multimap<int,string> to store several hundred thousand items (>300K), when we realized we needed to add more data for analysis. So we created a class that held a few items and the necessary overridden operators for stl and used a multimap<ourStruct,String>. This worked fine and didn't take much longer than before (with some test data), when we then realized an stl <list> would do just fine, as long as we sorted it after we finished adding all the items. To our surprise, we found that adding all items to multimap still easily beats the total time to add all items to list, and then sort.
This doesn't make sense to us EE types, since by our thinking every insert to multimap would have to traverse the list then tack it on to the end, where as with list we would just add on to the end (via push back), then hopefully the sort wouldn't take as long. 
One more factoid: we intially did the comparison test with out sorting the list and were thrilled to see significant speed ups in speed using list. Then we added the sort, and were a bit stunned...
Any of the CS gurus out there care to weigh in?

Answer (score 0):

Removed ref to hash .. Balanced tree is why only an n2 traverse is required.

Answer (score 0):

`std::multimap` uses a balanced tree<sup>1</sup>, so it does *not* traverse the entire list when you insert an item. The number of items traversed for an insert is approximately the base 2 logarithm of the number of items in the collection.

Based on what you've said, your best bet would probably be to put your data in a vector, and then sort.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, the standard doesn't directly require a balanced tree, but it requires ability to traverse in sorted order, and logarithmic complexity for insertions and deletions in the worst case, and I'm not aware of many other data structures that can meet that requirement.

Comment: I mis-stated. We realize it doesn't traverse the whole tree, just the branches that need to be (that logN thing). We also tested a vector and that was even slower, epecially during the addition phase. Thats what lead us to list...